# The property file is not found when it's in a jar

Tags: spring, properties, jar, classpath

I've got a problem with my property file since I deploy my application within jars. When it was just in the WEB-INF/classes directory, there was no problem. My problems occur only with properties files inside jars.

Let me explain. I will simplify my code.

My application deals with buisiness objects called IPX (it's not useful to know what it is)

There's a DAO class called IpxDaoImpl with string attributes, that are SQL queries

```
public class IpxDaoImpl implements IpxDao extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport {
  private String listAllIpxSql; // query for listing IPX in Database

  public void listAllIpx() {
    // Does a query in Database using the variable listAllIpxSql
    // ...
  }

  public void setListAllIpxSql(String listAllIpxSql) {
    this.listAllIpxSql = listAllIpxSql;
  }
}
```

This class is defined in a config xml file, called appContext-dao.xml. It contains :

```
<bean id="ipxDao" class="com.IpxDaoImpl" parent="myGenericDao">

  <property name="listAllIpxSql" value="${ipx.list}" />

</bean>
```

There is another config xml file, that tells how to load the properties files : appContext-commo-dao.xml. It contains :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:**/sql.properties" />
```

And there is a sql.properties file proper to queries about IPX. It contains :

```
ipx.list=SELECT * FROM IPX
```

Now, when I deploy my application in WEB-INF/classes, everything is fine. But we have an integration environement where we have to generate jars. All the files I've mentioned above are in the same jar. And then, when I deploy, I've got this error :
Could not resolve placeholder 'ipx.list'
It seems that the property file sql.properties is not found.

I've tried to extract this property file and put it in the WEB-INF/classes directory, with the proper folder. And now it works.

So, what is wrong with my code? Is it the placeholer ?
Thanks in advance.

Cedric

Comment: Not sure whether it's your problem, but there should not be an asterisk after "classpath" in your property placeholder.

Comment: Where is sql.properties stored in the project? And where is it in the resulting JAR that is built?

Comment: There are several sql.properties, in different folders but with a common root (something like com/mypackages).

Answer (score 0):

Try with `classpath:/sql.properties`

From reference:

> Please note that "classpath*:" when combined with Ant-style patterns
>   will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the
>   pattern starts, unless the actual target files reside in the file
>   system.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff for more info.

Comment: There are several sql.properties files, so I'll rather try classpath*:com/mypackages/**/sql.properties

Comment: It works! I've left classpath* but then I write the beginning of the common folder containing the different sql.properties files

Comment: So, this solution works :
classpath*:com/mypackages/**/sql.properties

Thank you !