# Issue of notfound class exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working on mvc-spring framework to cconnect to the data base I would like to create a file of properties.
so when I'm trying to compile my code I got a filenotfound exception depite I mention the location of file correctly.
I put the fb.propoperties file on META-INF folder.

**persistence.xml**

```
    <bean 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/db.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Création de la datasource -->
    <bean id="datasource"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <!--  <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
    <list>
    <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <!-- On spécifie ici les lieux où trouver les fichiers de persistence -->
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- On spécifie ici les sources de données à utiliser, locale ou distante -->
        <property name="dataSources">
            <map>
                <entry key="localDataSource" value-ref="datasource" />
                <!--<entry key="remoteDataSource" value-ref="remote-db" />-->
            </map>
        </property>
        <!-- On spécifie ici la sources de données par défaut si aucune source de données n'est disponible -->
        <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ERP_PCD"></property>
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ERP_PCD"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean> 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean name="opmanager" class="com.ensi.dao.opmanagerImpl"> </bean>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ensi.dao"></context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

**stacktrace**

```
{226 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext -   Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4e838143:  startup date [Wed May 07 00:19:19 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    403 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading   XML bean definitions from URL  [file:/C:/Users/housseminfo/workspace/ERP_PCD/target/classes/META-  INF/applicationContext.xml]
  1001 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner -   JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
   1351 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer    - Loading properties file from class path resource [classpath*:META-INF/db.properties]
    1353 [main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -    Destroying singletons in    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6fe03f3b: defining    beans   [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,datasource,persis tenceUnitManager,entityManagerFactory,entityManager,transactionManager,org.springframework. aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,opmanager,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:META-INF/db.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.ensi.dao.Maintest.main(Maintest.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath*:META-INF/db.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
    ... 6 more}
```

Comment: You have a `</beans>` but no `<beans>`

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities are:

1. It's a typo since you say that the file is fb.properties, but the reference to it is db.properties.
2. You're not copying the file to your classpath directory, maybe your target directory or into your jar, depending on how you're building your project.
3. You need a / before META-INF, as I found in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044747/the-property-file-is-not-found-when-its-in-a-jar).